# Tikz matrix diagram issue

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees

I am trying to recreate the below in Tikz, but the code below isnt running - it hangs and doesnt complete. I am struggling a bit with Tikz and getting my head around it. I need to draw lots of diagrams for my thesis and this is just one...

[image]

My code so far....

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}

%% Package for creating diagrams
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, arrows, positioning, fit, backgrounds, matrix, shadows, arrows.meta, positioning, chains, scopes}

\tikzset{
    1/.style={fill=red!30},
    2/.style={fill=blue!30},
    3/.style={fill=orange!30},
    4/.style={fill=green!30},
    5/.style={fill=red},
    arrow/.style={thick,->,>=stealth},
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix(m)[matrix of nodes,column sep=0.75cm, row sep=0.5cm,
    nodes={rectangle, rounded corners, text width=2.5cm, minimum height=1cm,text centered, draw=black,anchor=west},
    ]{
        \node[draw=none](int){}; & \node[1](model){Socio-technical theory or model};\\
        \node[1](social-methods){Social Methods} & \node[1](technical-methods){Technical Methods};\\
        \node[1](social-data){Social Data} & \node[1](technical-data){Technical Data};\\
        \node[draw=none](int){}; & \node[1](socio-analysis){Socio-technical analysis};\\
    };


    \end{tikzpicture}

    \caption{A conceptual model for socio-technical research (reproduced from ...) } 
    \label{fig:socio-technical model}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

When you use `matrix of nodes`, the nodes in the matrix do no longer need the `\node{...};` wrapper. Fixing this and adding a few elements (with the information from [your more recent question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/517278/194703) on how things should supposedly look like) leads to

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
%% Package for creating diagrams
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit,matrix, backgrounds}
\tikzset{
    1/.style={fill=red!30},
    2/.style={fill=blue!30},
    3/.style={fill=orange!30},
    4/.style={fill=green!30},
    5/.style={fill=red},
    arrow/.style={thick,->,>=stealth},
    back group/.style={fill=yellow!20,rounded corners, draw=black!50, dashed, inner xsep=15pt, inner ysep=10pt},
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering

    \begin{tikzpicture}[box/.style={rectangle, rounded corners, 
        text width=2.5cm, minimum height=1cm,text centered, draw=black},
        font=\sffamily]
    \matrix(m)[matrix of nodes,column sep=3.5em, row sep=0.5cm,nodes={box,
    anchor=center},row 1/.style={nodes={2}},
    row 2/.style={nodes={3}},row 3/.style={nodes={4}},]
     (mat){
        Social Methods & Technical Methods\\
        Social Data & Technical Data\\
        Social Analysis & Technical analysis\\
    };
    \begin{scope}[on background layer,nodes={back group}]
     \node[fit=(mat-1-1)(mat.north-|mat-1-1)(mat.south-|mat-1-1),inner
     xsep=1em,inner ysep=1.5em,draw,yshift=1ex,
         label={[anchor=north west]north west:Social design}](F1){};
     \node[fit=(mat-1-2)(mat.north-|mat-1-2)(mat.south-|mat-1-2),inner
     xsep=1em,inner ysep=1.5em,draw,yshift=1ex,
         label={[anchor=north west]north west:Technical design}](F2){};
    \end{scope}  
    \node[box,above=3em of mat,text width=3.2cm,minimum height=1.3cm,1](model)
        {Socio-technical theory or model};
    \begin{scope}[arrow]
     \foreach \X in {1,2}
     {\draw (model) -- (F\X);
      \draw (mat-1-\X) -- (mat-2-\X);
      \draw (mat-2-\X) -- (mat-3-\X);
      }
     \draw (mat-3-1.east) -- ([yshift=-1em]mat-3-1.east-|F1.east);
     \draw (mat-3-2.west) -- ([yshift=-1em]mat-3-2.west-|F2.west);
     \draw (mat-1-2) -- (mat-2-1);
    \end{scope}

    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{A conceptual model for socio-technical research (reproduced from
    \dots).} 
    \label{fig:socio-technical model}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the second and third line of this snippet your code misses a semicolon before the &. So change this:

```
\node[draw=none](int){}; & \node[1](model){Socio-technical theory or model};\\
\node[1](social-methods){Social Methods} & \node[1](technical-methods){Technical Methods};\\
\node[1](social-data){Social Data} & \node[1](technical-data){Technical Data};\\
\node[draw=none](int){}; & \node[1](socio-analysis){Socio-technical analysis};\\
```

to this:

```
\node[draw=none](int){}; & \node[1](model){Socio-technical theory or model};\\
\node[1](social-methods){Social Methods}; & \node[1](technical-methods){Technical Methods};\\
\node[1](social-data){Social Data}; & \node[1](technical-data){Technical Data};\\
\node[draw=none](int){}; & \node[1](socio-analysis){Socio-technical analysis};\\
```

and it renders:

[image]