# How can I add a figure inside a TikZ Matrix?

Tags: graphics, tikz-matrix

I have a TikZ matrix that is similar to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/517263/tikz-matrix-diagram-issue) :

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
%% Package for creating diagrams
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit,matrix, backgrounds}
\tikzset{
    1/.style={fill=red!30},
    2/.style={fill=blue!30},
    3/.style={fill=orange!30},
    4/.style={fill=green!30},
    5/.style={fill=red},
    arrow/.style={thick,->,>=stealth},
    back group/.style={fill=yellow!20,rounded corners, draw=black!50, dashed, inner xsep=15pt, inner ysep=10pt},
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering

    \begin{tikzpicture}[box/.style={rectangle, rounded corners, 
        text width=2.5cm, minimum height=1cm,text centered, draw=black},
        font=\sffamily]
    \matrix(m)[matrix of nodes,column sep=3.5em, row sep=0.5cm,nodes={box,
    anchor=center},row 1/.style={nodes={2}},
    row 2/.style={nodes={3}},row 3/.style={nodes={4}},]
     (mat){
        Social Methods & Technical Methods\\
        Social Data & Technical Data\\
        Social Analysis & Technical analysis\\
    };
    \begin{scope}[on background layer,nodes={back group}]
     \node[fit=(mat-1-1)(mat.north-|mat-1-1)(mat.south-|mat-1-1),inner
     xsep=1em,inner ysep=1.5em,draw,yshift=1ex,
         label={[anchor=north west]north west:Social design}](F1){};
     \node[fit=(mat-1-2)(mat.north-|mat-1-2)(mat.south-|mat-1-2),inner
     xsep=1em,inner ysep=1.5em,draw,yshift=1ex,
         label={[anchor=north west]north west:Technical design}](F2){};
    \end{scope}  
    \node[box,above=3em of mat,text width=3.2cm,minimum height=1.3cm,1](model)
        {Socio-technical theory or model};
    \begin{scope}[arrow]
     \foreach \X in {1,2}
     {\draw (model) -- (F\X);
      \draw (mat-1-\X) -- (mat-2-\X);
      \draw (mat-2-\X) -- (mat-3-\X);
      }
     \draw (mat-3-1.east) -- ([yshift=-1em]mat-3-1.east-|F1.east);
     \draw (mat-3-2.west) -- ([yshift=-1em]mat-3-2.west-|F2.west);
     \draw (mat-1-2) -- (mat-2-1);
    \end{scope}

    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{A conceptual model for socio-technical research (reproduced from
    \dots).} 
    \label{fig:socio-technical model}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

However, on the left matrix I want to add a figure to fit inside the rounded square (maroon) as follows:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm guessing, that the image should be inserted like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
%% Package for creating diagrams
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds, fit, matrix, positioning}
\tikzset{
    1/.style={fill=red!30},
    2/.style={fill=blue!30},
    3/.style={fill=orange!30},
    4/.style={fill=green!30},
    5/.style={fill=red},
every edge/.style = {draw, thick, -stealth},
    box/.style={draw=red, rounded corners,
            text width=24mm, minimum height=12mm,
            align=center, font=\sffamily},
  FIT/.style args = {#1/#2}{draw, rounded corners, dashed, fill=yellow!30,
            inner xsep=1em, inner ysep=2em, yshift=1em,
            label={[anchor=north]north:#1},
            fit=#2}
}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
    \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (m) [matrix of nodes,
             column sep=3.5em, row sep=0.5cm,
             nodes={box, anchor=center},
             row 1/.style={nodes={2}},
             row 2/.style={nodes={3}},
             row 3/.style={nodes={4}}
             ]
{
Social Methods  & Technical Methods \\
Social Data     & Technical Data    \\
Social Analysis & Technical analysis\\
};
    \begin{scope}[on background layer]
\node (F1) [FIT=Social design/(m-1-1)(m-3-1)] {};
\node (F2) [FIT=Technical design/(m-1-2)(m-3-2)]    {};
    \end{scope}
\node (F3)  [FIT=/(m-1-1)(m-3-1), yshift=-1em, inner sep=0pt] {};
\node (model)   [box, text width=32mm,
                 above=22mm of m]  {Socio-technical theory or model};
% arrows
\foreach \X in {1,2}
{
\draw   (model)   edge (F\X)
        (m-1-\X)  edge (m-2-\X) 
        (m-2-\X)  edge (m-3-\X);
}
\draw   (m-3-1.east)    edge (m-3-1.south -| F1.east) 
        (m-3-2.west)    edge (m-3-2.south -| F2.west) 
        (m-1-2)         edge (m-2-1);
% image in clip
\path[clip]
    (F3.south west) |- (F3.north east) |- (F3.south east);
\node at (F3) {\includegraphics[scale=1.3]{example-image-duck}};

\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{A conceptual model for socio-technical research (reproduced from
    \dots).}
\label{fig:socio-technical model}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes thats exactly what I am looking for!

Answer (score 3):

You could add a node at (F1) and `\includegraphics{some image}` inside the node.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
%% Package for creating diagrams
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit,matrix, backgrounds}
\tikzset{
    1/.style={fill=red!30},
    2/.style={fill=blue!30},
    3/.style={fill=orange!30},
    4/.style={fill=green!30},
    5/.style={fill=red},
    arrow/.style={thick,->,>=stealth},
    back group/.style={fill=yellow!20,rounded corners, draw=black!50, dashed, inner xsep=15pt, inner ysep=10pt},
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering

    \begin{tikzpicture}[box/.style={rectangle, rounded corners, 
        text width=2.5cm, minimum height=1cm,text centered, draw=black},
        font=\sffamily]
    \matrix(m)[matrix of nodes,column sep=3.5em, row sep=0.5cm,nodes={box,
    anchor=center},row 1/.style={nodes={2}},
    row 2/.style={nodes={3}},row 3/.style={nodes={4}},]
     (mat){
        Social Methods & Technical Methods\\
        Social Data & Technical Data\\
        Social Analysis & Technical analysis\\
    };
    \begin{scope}[on background layer,nodes={back group}]
     \node[fit=(mat-1-1)(mat.north-|mat-1-1)(mat.south-|mat-1-1),inner
     xsep=1em,inner ysep=1.5em,draw,yshift=1ex,
         label={[anchor=north west]north west:Social design}](F1){};
     \node[fit=(mat-1-2)(mat.north-|mat-1-2)(mat.south-|mat-1-2),inner
     xsep=1em,inner ysep=1.5em,draw,yshift=1ex,
         label={[anchor=north west]north west:Technical design}](F2){};
    \end{scope}  
    \node[box,above=3em of mat,text width=3.2cm,minimum height=1.3cm,1](model)
        {Socio-technical theory or model};
    \begin{scope}[arrow]
     \foreach \X in {1,2}
     {\draw (model) -- (F\X);
      \draw (mat-1-\X) -- (mat-2-\X);
      \draw (mat-2-\X) -- (mat-3-\X);
      }
     \draw (mat-3-1.east) -- ([yshift=-1em]mat-3-1.east-|F1.east);
     \draw (mat-3-2.west) -- ([yshift=-1em]mat-3-2.west-|F2.west);
     \draw (mat-1-2) -- (mat-2-1);
    \end{scope}
    \node [below=4pt,anchor=center] at (F1) {\includegraphics[width=2.8cm,height=4.1cm]{example-image}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{A conceptual model for socio-technical research (reproduced from
    \dots).} 
    \label{fig:socio-technical model}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 This makes so much sense now!