# \path[clip] ruins existing diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, nodes, fit

I have a node diagram where I want to add the two images. I am using `\path[clip]` but it only works if there is no other `\path[clip]`. I even added `\begin{pgfinterruptboundingbox}` to isolate the image from other but still it doesnt work. It only work when I remove one of the image. The example is taken from [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/646082/how-can-i-add-a-figure-inside-a-tikz-matrix) post.

The objective is to have the image in both the matrix nodes.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
%% Package for creating diagrams
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds, fit, matrix, positioning}
\tikzset{
    1/.style={fill=red!30},
    2/.style={fill=blue!30},
    3/.style={fill=orange!30},
    4/.style={fill=green!30},
    5/.style={fill=red},
every edge/.style = {draw, thick, -stealth},
    box/.style={draw=red, rounded corners,
            text width=24mm, minimum height=12mm,
            align=center, font=\sffamily},
  FIT/.style args = {#1/#2}{draw, rounded corners, dashed, fill=yellow!30,
            inner xsep=1em, inner ysep=2em, yshift=1em,
            label={[anchor=north]north:#1},
            fit=#2}
}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
    \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (m) [matrix of nodes,
             column sep=3.5em, row sep=0.5cm,
             nodes={box, anchor=center},
             row 1/.style={nodes={2}},
             row 2/.style={nodes={3}},
             row 3/.style={nodes={4}}
             ]
{
Social Methods  & Technical Methods \\
Social Data     & Technical Data    \\
Social Analysis & Technical analysis\\
};
    \begin{scope}[on background layer]
\node (F1) [FIT=Social design/(m-1-1)(m-3-1)] {};
\node (F2) [FIT=Technical design/(m-1-2)(m-3-2)]    {};
    \end{scope}
\node (F3)  [FIT=/(m-1-1)(m-3-1), yshift=-1em, inner sep=0pt] {};
\node (model)   [box, text width=32mm,
                 above=22mm of m]  {Socio-technical theory or model};
% arrows
\foreach \X in {1,2}
{
\draw   (model)   edge (F\X)
        (m-1-\X)  edge (m-2-\X) 
        (m-2-\X)  edge (m-3-\X);
}
\draw   (m-3-1.east)    edge (m-3-1.south -| F1.east) 
        (m-3-2.west)    edge (m-3-2.south -| F2.west) 
        (m-1-2)         edge (m-2-1);
% image in clip
\begin{pgfinterruptboundingbox}

\path[clip]
    (F3.south west) |- (F3.north east) |- (F3.south east);
\node at (F3) {\includegraphics[scale=1.3]{example-image-duck}};
\end{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
\begin{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
\path[clip]
    (F2.south west) |- (F2.north east) |- (F2.south east);
\node at (F2) {\includegraphics[scale=1.3]{example-image-duck}};
\end{pgfinterruptboundingbox}

\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{A conceptual model for socio-technical research (reproduced from
    \dots).}
\label{fig:socio-technical model}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put each clip into a different scope.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
%% Package for creating diagrams
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds, fit, matrix, positioning}
\tikzset{
    1/.style={fill=red!30},
    2/.style={fill=blue!30},
    3/.style={fill=orange!30},
    4/.style={fill=green!30},
    5/.style={fill=red},
every edge/.style = {draw, thick, -stealth},
    box/.style={draw=red, rounded corners,
            text width=24mm, minimum height=12mm,
            align=center, font=\sffamily},
  FIT/.style args = {#1/#2}{draw, rounded corners, dashed, fill=yellow!30,
            inner xsep=1em, inner ysep=2em, yshift=1em,
            label={[anchor=north]north:#1},
            fit=#2}
}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
    \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (m) [matrix of nodes,
             column sep=3.5em, row sep=0.5cm,
             nodes={box, anchor=center},
             row 1/.style={nodes={2}},
             row 2/.style={nodes={3}},
             row 3/.style={nodes={4}}
             ]
{
Social Methods  & Technical Methods \\
Social Data     & Technical Data    \\
Social Analysis & Technical analysis\\
};
    \begin{scope}[on background layer]
\node (F1) [FIT=Social design/(m-1-1)(m-3-1)] {};
\node (F2) [FIT=Technical design/(m-1-2)(m-3-2)]    {};
    \end{scope}
\node (F3)  [FIT=/(m-1-1)(m-3-1), yshift=-1em, inner sep=0pt] {};
\node (model)   [box, text width=32mm,
                 above=22mm of m]  {Socio-technical theory or model};
% arrows
\foreach \X in {1,2}
{
\draw   (model)   edge (F\X)
        (m-1-\X)  edge (m-2-\X) 
        (m-2-\X)  edge (m-3-\X);
}
\draw   (m-3-1.east)    edge (m-3-1.south -| F1.east) 
        (m-3-2.west)    edge (m-3-2.south -| F2.west) 
        (m-1-2)         edge (m-2-1);
% image in clip

\begin{scope}
\path[clip]
    (F3.south west) |- (F3.north east) |- (F3.south east);
\node at (F3) {\includegraphics[scale=1.3]{example-image-duck}};
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}
\path[clip]
    (F2.south west) |- (F2.north east) |- (F2.south east);
\node at (F2) {\includegraphics[scale=1.3]{example-image-duck}};
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{A conceptual model for socio-technical research (reproduced from
    \dots).}
\label{fig:socio-technical model}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: I see so isnt that what `pgfinterruptboundingbox` do, it creates a bounding box scope?

Comment: Changes made inside a scope are local to the scope (which is not true for all environments). pgfinterruptboundingbox is used to prevent the bounding box from including certain points, such as control points for Bezier curves or when doing geometric construction.